# Showing multiple values while joining tables

Tags: mysql

Hello I am trying following query 
I am having four tables `post_messages` `post_message_users`, `link_details`,`tags`
post_messages has 1:N relation ship with `link_details`,`tags`
 tables
I am writing following query to fetch related data from all tables.
But problem is that it is showing same value many times.

```
           SELECT
             p_m.*,
             p_m_u.*,
             GROUP_CONCAT( tags.tag SEPARATOR ';') 
             AS 'MESSAGE_TAGS', 
             GROUP_CONCAT( linkdtl.link_id SEPARATOR ';') 
             AS `LINK_ID`, 
             GROUP_CONCAT( linkdtl.link SEPARATOR ';') 
             AS 'LINK', 
             GROUP_CONCAT( linkdtl.link_title SEPARATOR ';') 
             AS 'LINK_TITLE' 
             FROM post_message_users AS p_m_u 
             LEFT JOIN post_messages AS p_m 
             ON p_m.messageid = p_m_u.messageid 
             LEFT JOIN tags 
             ON p_m.messageid=tags.message_id 
             LEFT JOIN link_details AS linkdtl
             ON p_m_u.messageid=linkdtl.message_id

             GROUP BY p_m_u.messageid,p_m_u.received_by,tags.message_id 
             ORDER BY p_m_u.adddate DESC
```

How to resolve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `DISTINCT` in your `GROUP_CONCAT` clause

```
GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT tags.tag SEPARATOR ';') 


SELECT 
  p_m.*,
  p_m_u.*,
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT tags.tag SEPARATOR ';') AS 'MESSAGE_TAGS',
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT linkdtl.link_id SEPARATOR ';') AS `LINK_ID`,
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT linkdtl.link SEPARATOR ';') AS 'LINK',
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT linkdtl.link_title SEPARATOR ';') AS 'LINK_TITLE' ....
```

Comment: But when i am having two same tags like aa;xx;aa;xx it is showing only two. But there are 4 entries in `tags` table . how to show all four without repeating.

Comment: @manishSahu there are actually two tags not four aa is repeating twice xx is also repeating twice so there is actually two tags not four right